# Why does my java compiler not recognise so many symbols?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

if someone has already asked this question, or one similar, then I'm sorry and I would be very grateful if they could let me know where the answer to this question is. I'm pretty new to java, however, I have a programming assignment that is due 07/05(May)/15 (We have to create a flocking simulation, but this isn't really what my question's about.). I am currently typing up code to compile in order to help me understand how to create graphics for the simulation. However, whenever I compile my code, my compiler keeps on saying that it hasn't recognised a lot/pretty much any of the symbols I typed. For example (Just so you know, I'm using Atom as a text editor, and the command prompt to compile my code, but I have also tried the same pieces of code in NetBeans):

**Source Code:**

```
package Simulator;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Simulator extends JFrame{

public Simulator(){

setTitle("Simulator");

setSize(500, 500);

setResizable(false);

setVisible(true);

setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


  }

public void paint(Graphics g){

g.drawstring("HelloWorld!", 75, 75);

}

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Simulator();

    }
}
```

**Compiler's reaction:**

```
        *C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Java>javac Simulator.java
         Simulator.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
         g.drawstring("HelloWorld!", 75, 75);
          ^
         symbol:   method drawstring(String,int,int)
         location: variable g of type Graphics
         1 error*
```

Thank you for reading all this, and I'm sorry for interrupting you day by making you read all this, but it would be such a help, thank you!!!!

Comment: Putting "urgent" in the title does the opposite of what you expect: it pulls people away. That's because they only take time to read a few words from the title, and you wasted one. I suggest dropping this word. Also, bold is better used in moderation.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for telling me this, I'l do it now, sorry, I was just really worried and I've never used something like this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) says that it's spelled drawString, with an uppercase S. Java is case sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

Java is case sensitive. That means `drawstring` and `drawString` (note the upper case `S`) are different. You need to use:

```
     g.drawString("HelloWorld!", 75, 75);
```